# Fonts on PhoneGap Android and iOS differ?

Tags: android, ios, font-size

I have successfully create my phonegap app and I find the same code results in perfectly readable sized fonts on iOS but difficult to read font size on an Android. I would have expected them to be similar.

Has anyone else faced similar issue? How to build once and make readable on both? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a post that related to webviews that helped but I reference it here in case someone (like me) who is new to phonegap fails to make the connection.

[font size different on ios and android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625475/font-size-different-on-ios-and-android)

My viewport inside my html page was

```
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

I know little about viewport other than having read references that I should have it.

I took the first of @louielouie suggestions and removed reference to, rebuilt my app in the phonegap build service and the app results look similar on an ios ipod touch and a samsung galaxy tab 4.